# how to call a function class javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, function, class, frontend

I wanted to create a class with private parameters and functions to access the data I want. You can see this :

```
export class Product {
  private name: string;
  private type: string;
  private longDetail: string;
  private shortDetail: string;
  private stock: number;
  private price: number;
  private linkImage: string;
  private id: number;

  constructor(
    name: string,
    type: string,
    longDetail: string,
    shortDetail: string,
    stock: number,
    price: number,
    linkImage: string,
    id: number
  ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
    this.longDetail = longDetail;
    this.shortDetail = shortDetail;
    this.stock = stock;
    this.price = price;
    this.linkImage = linkImage;
    this.id = id;
  }

  getName(): string {
    return this.name;
  }
  getType(): string {
    return this.type;
  }
  getLongDetail(): string {
    return this.longDetail;
  }
  getShortDetail(): string {
    return this.shortDetail;
  }
  getStock(): number {
    return this.stock;
  }
  getPrice(): number {
    return this.price;
  }
  getLinkImage(): string {
    return this.linkImage;
  }
  getId(): number {
    return this.id;
  }
}
```

And when I want to call a function in a component I am told :

> ProductListComponent.html:15 ERROR TypeError: newProduct.getName is not a function

Do you have a solution ? Thank you very much in advance !

EDIT :

This is the code called after the click in front end

```
addProductBasket(newProduct: Product) {
  const newClientBasket = this.createNewClientBasketWithAdd(
    this.clientBasket.getValue(),
    newProduct
  )
  this.clientBasket.next(newClientBasket)
  console.log(newClientBasket)
}

private createNewClientBasketWithAdd(
  oldClientBasket: BasketProduct[],
  newProduct: Product
): BasketProduct[] {
  const found = oldClientBasket.find((product) => {
    if (product.getId() === newProduct.getId()) {
      product.addOneProduct()
    }
  })

  if (found === undefined) {
    console.log(newProduct.getName())
    oldClientBasket.push(
      new BasketProduct(
        newProduct.getName(),
        newProduct.getType(),
        newProduct.getLongDetail(),
        newProduct.getShortDetail(),
        newProduct.getStock(),
        newProduct.getPrice(),
        newProduct.getLinkImage(),
        newProduct.getId()
      )
    )
  }
  return oldClientBasket
}
```

It's my apiservice to get data

```
export class ApiService {
  private dataApi: BehaviorSubject<Product[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Product[]>([]);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getDataFromApi();
  }
  private getDataFromApi(){
    this.http
      .get<Product[]>("../../assets/data.json")
      .toPromise()
      .then((data) => this.dataApi.next(data));
  }
  public getData():Observable<Product[]>{
    return this.dataApi.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you create newProduct ?

Comment: In my front end I display a list of products and when I click on one of them I arrive on my function which with the object in parameter. When i do

"console.log(newProduct)"

They show me the whole object so I think the object is good

Comment: Please post the code you are using from the other component.

Comment: yes i have edit :)

Comment: Show how the product is created. It s likely that you are retrieving product data directly from a httpClient.get call and casting result as a Product without actually creating a new instance

Comment: Oh yes David ! I have edit to show and I think you're right, do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After David's help in commenting, I understood that I had to instantiate the data I receive in http client.

I then modified the constructor and my client http get

```
  constructor(obj: any) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
  }
```

and

```
private getDataFromApi(){
    this.http
      .get<Product[]>("../../assets/data.json").pipe()
      .toPromise()
      .then((data) => {
        const productList = data.map(product => new Product(product));
        this.dataApi.next(productList)});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have an instance of `Product` class before accessing its methods.

```
var newProduct = new Product();
newProduct.getName();
```